# Passing a parameter to an event handler in the parent class from a child class ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eventhandler

I am trying to pass a parameter to an event handler in a parent class, but am having some difficulty. I have done a good amount of research and am close to answer, but something's not quite working. Below I will give a basic hypothetical example of what I would like to do that doesn't work.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
       constructor(props){
           super(props);
           this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
       }

       handleClick(i){
           return event => console.log(i);
       }

       render(){
          return <Child onClick={this.handleClick}></button>;
       }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
       render() {
            const myVar = 2;
            return <button onClick={this.props.onClick(myVar)}></button>;
       }
}
```

I know the onClick prop that is passed to the Child is not a function, so I am unable to pass parameters directly to it. What is the best way to go about doing this? Thanks for you help!

Comment: If the onClick props is not a function, how can you call it. It has to be a function.

Comment: What do you want your code to do in the end? Currently, it seems like your code would run fine but wouldn't do anything meaningful

Comment: @Taylor Gray consider accepting the answer which solved your problem too.

Comment: @godof23 both Josh Pittman and your answers were very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the following update to your code

```
class Child extends React.Component{
       render(){
            const var = 2;
            return <button onClick={ () => {this.props.onClick(var)} }</button>;
       }
}
```

Furthermore, you should refactor the following method used by parent as so. You are passing `e` needlessly.

```
handleClick(i){
    console.log(i);
}
```

The onClick on your child component was immediately invoked instead of waiting for the onClick event to fire.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do

```
handleClick(i){
           return (e => {console.log(i)});
       }
```

instead, try

```
handleClick(i){
          console.log(i)
       }
```

and move the event handling to where it is being called. So instead of

```
<button onClick={this.props.onClick(var)}</button>
```

You want to try

```
<button onClick={e => this.props.onClick(var)}</button>
```

Comment: There are other ways to bind event handlers, above is probably the simples to get started. Here is more reading if interested https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-best-way-to-bind-event-handlers-in-react-282db2cf1530